# pass variable into string in symfony and jquery

Tags: php, jquery, symfony

I want to pass the id into a string but always I get an error

```
  var c = document.getElementById("predefinedMessage");
    var id= c.selectedIndex;
    var text= "{{  form.predefinedMessage.vars.choices[id].data.message }}";

    $('message').val(text);

});
```

how I can pass the id in the text variable

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Key id  for array with keys "1, 2" does not exist in ACMBundle:message:index.html.twig

Comment: Is it how you're getting your value from variable `c`?  See update

Comment: when i put 1 instead of id, it work fine, but when i put the id or c.selectedIndex, I get an error like Key "+ id +" for array with keys "1, 2" does not exist  or Variable "id" does not exist in ...

Comment: That's because getElementById will only ever bring back a single value.  There should only ever be 1 ID of the same name on the page.  If you want multiple names assigned to some elements you need to use `class="className"`

Comment: I got the same Error if I affect a value to the id. for example: id=1  and then var text= "{{  form.predefinedMessage.vars.choices[" + id + "].data.message }}" I got the same error,  the problem come from the id, I can't pass it into {{  form.predefinedMessage.vars.choices[" + id + "].data.message }}"

Comment: <script>
    $('#add').click(function(){
        var c = document.getElementById("Pushtype_predefinedMessage");
        var id= c.selectedIndex;
        var text3= "{{  form.predefinedMessage.vars.choices["+ id +"].data.message }}";
       var text= $( "#predefinedMessage option:selected " ).text();
   
        $('#message').val(text3);

    });
</script>

Answer (score 0):

If the element that you're selecting is a drop down list, I suggest the following code using jQuery as you're already using it:

```
// Select by the ID predefinedMessage
var dropDown = $("select#predefinedMessage");

// Get the selected index from the dropdown
var selectedIndex = dropDown.find("option:selected").index();

var text = "{{  form.predefinedMessage.vars.choices[" + selectedIndex + "].data.message }}";

$('message').val(text);
```

Comment: Key id for array with keys "1, 2" does not exist in ACMBundle:message:index.html.twig

Comment: the predefined message is a dropdown list

Comment: Key " + selectedIndex + " for array with keys "1, 2" does not exist,  As I told you, the problem is how i can pass the variable id.